# Erlang ODBC Connection challenges

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, erlang

I have Oracle 10g Release 2 running, and from my sqlplus, the Oracle DB listener is up and running and i can issue and execute commands to the database, as shown below

```
bash-3.00$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Oct 20 18:33:33 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

SQL> connect system/muzaaya
Connected.
SQL> create table fruits (
  2  fruit_name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  3  fruit_biological_name VARCHAR2(50),
  4  fruit_quantity INT NOT NULL,
  5  fruit_location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL>
```

I then go here: **http://www.datadirect.com/download.html** to get my self an ODBC Connector for Oracle. I download it and install it on Windows 7 64 bit. I then go ahead and configure Data Sources using my windows `Windows ODBC Administrator`. I create a DSN called `D1`, enter description, server name, client version, username and password and lastly i test the connection and the connection is perfectly established!

After this, i go to my erlang and start our odbc application, this is what happens below:

```
1> odbc:start().
ok
2> odbc:connect("DSN=D1;UID=system;PWD=muzaaya", []).
{error,"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an 
architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application SQLSTATE IS: 
IM014 Connection to database failed."}
```

**What does this mean ?  and how do i correct it so as to connect to my Oracle DB from Erlang ?**

**Can some one give me any Oracle specific ODBC connection examples (if there any) from Erlang or some related experience in a different language so as i can make comparison and change here and there ?**

**Are there more parameters that need to be specified in our Erlang ODBC connection in order to connect to ORACLE, say for example `tnsnames.ora,spfile, or pfile` , other than the ones i have already specified in the ODBC settings?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like an "architecture mismatch". I have never used odbc before, but a quick Google search returned the following result:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx

Where, you read:

> If you use the 64-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove a DSN that
>   connects to a 32-bit driver, for example, Driver do Microsoft Access
>   (*.mdb), you will receive the following error message:
>
> **The specified DSN  contains an architecture mismatch between the
>   Driver and Application**

And then a solution is proposed:

> To resolve this error, use the 32-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or
>   remove the DSN.